# C# дергается лифт 2D юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Лифт едет до указанной точки, но постоянно дергается.
Нужно сделать так,чтобы он спускался плавно.

Вот код:

```
     using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ElevatorMoving : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform pointToGo;
    public float speed;

    public bool colliding = false;


    private Vector2 movement;


    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            {

                float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointToGo.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
        }
    }

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    coll.transform.parent = null;
}
```

}

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` - это с пердыдущего фрейма

Comment: Думаю поможет [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: **нельзя двигать физические объекты через tranform**, это не совет и не "мнение", даже если написать всю логику правильно, как указано в ответе Yaroslav, все равно возможны баги и неправильное поведение физики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рывки следствие твоей логики: персонаж касается ливта -> ливт сдвигается -> персонаж больше не касается сдвинутого ливта и падает -> падает на ливт -> цикл.

```
public bool Colliding = false;
Vector3 BasePosition;
Vector3 TargetPosition;
bool MoveAction;
float MoveTimer;
float MoveTime = 1;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !Colliding) {
        colliding = true;
        MoveAction = true;
        MoveTimer = 0;
        BasePosition = transform.position;
    }
}

void Update () {
    if (MoveAction) {
        MoveTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        float Way = MoveTimer/MoveTime;
        if (Way < 1) {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(BasePosition, TargetPosition, Way);
        } else {
            transform.position = TargetPosition;
            MoveAction = false;
        }
    }
}
```